# How can I select from an open dialog an ".app" that is part of the contents of another ".app"?

Tags: macos, applications, dialog

I have an open dialog where I have to select an `.app`. But the application that I look for is packaged / part of the `Content` of another `.app`:

> Application / MyParent.app / Contents / MyChild.app

How can I trigger the **Show Package Contents** (that I see in Finder) from the Open dialog. Or is there another way to change the standard Open dialog to take a path or to navigate on the real file system paths?

Comment: Untested. Try opening the Contents on the Desktop then dragging the app into the dialog box. It works for regular folders, on phone right now so can’t test.

Comment: This trick worked. Thanks! You can post it as an answer.

Comment: Will do, once I get home to my computer. Glad it worked for you :)

Comment: Actually, I still can't test it as standard, because I have a dialog enhancer which overrides the Mac's default behaviour. Seems there are several ways to do it though.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer @tetsujin gave you in the comment, you can press cmd+shift+G in the open dialog to open an interface that lets you navigate to arbitrary folders. This has just been updated in Monterey (works with previous versions, it's just cooler in Monterey as it has a very helpful autocompletion).

You can use this trick in the Finder too, it's very useful to go look for stuff inside your Library folder.

Answer (score 0):

In the Open dialog, change the visualization from Icon to either Column or List. Both options allow you to open .app's like folders.